# Restarting daemon built in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, daemon

I am trying to restart a daemon called site_checker.rb using SSH commands through PuTTY. This file is located in:

```
/home/MYUSERNAME/web/current/lib/daemons
```

After logging into my website, which is built with Ruby on Rails, I see the following on-screen:

```
[MYUSERNAME@MYUSERNAME ~]$
```

From here, I enter

```
[MYUSERNAME@MYUSERNAME ~]$ cd web
```

and then

```
[MYUSERNAME@MYUSERNAME ~/web]$ script/daemons start
```

However, I get an error:

```
-bash: script/daemons: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to start `/home/MYUSERNAME/web/lib/daemons` while you claim your script is actually in `/home/MYUSERNAME/web/current/lib/daemons`. You are missing the `current`.

Comment: @Holger_Just, thanks so much for your post! Will you clarify specifically what I should be typing after `[MYUSERNAME@MYUSERNAME ~]$`

I tried:

`[MYUSERNAME@MYUSERNAME ~]$ cd web/current`

and then

`[MYUSERNAME@MYUSERNAME ~/web/current]$ script/daemons start`

but received the same error.

Comment: An update: I changed to root by doing `su -` and entering my password. Then, I used the command `/home/USERNAME/web/current/lib/daemons/site_checker.rb start` and received this response:
`/bin/sh: line 1: /home/USERNAME/web/current/lib/daemons/site_checker.rb: cannot execute [Permission denied]` I'm confused. How could "root" be denied? Is there a better approach to getting this site_checker.rb restarted?